# Why can't access loaded swf files?

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am embedding swf libraries, using swf 2.1.1 with openfl 3.3.9

```
<haxelib name="swf" />
<library path="Assets/compact-assets-cc.swf" id="Compo" preload="true"/>
<library path="Assets/led.swf" id="Led" preload="true"/>
```

but when android app starts after successful compilation, I get those errors:

> --------- beginning of main
>
> I/trace   (28156): Assets.hx:413: [Assets] There is no String asset with an ID of "libraries/Compo.json"
>
> I/trace   (28156): Assets.hx:413: [Assets] There is no String asset with an ID of "libraries/Led.json"

Any idea what could be the problem?

**EDIT**

I tried to use the default name in xml file:

, but I get:

```
I/trace   (12750): Assets.hx:413: [Assets] There is no String asset with an ID of "libraries/library.json"
I/trace   (14250): Assets.hx:413: [Assets] There is no String asset with an ID of "libraries/library.json"
```

If I use swf 2.1.2, I get this error:

```
mac:client Apple$ haxelib run lime test ./project.xml android -release
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/actions/ActionUnknown.hx:14: characters 3-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field skipBytes
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:59: characters 20-33 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:60: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:61: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:62: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:63: characters 13-27 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:64: characters 13-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:65: characters 18-30 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:73: characters 2-16 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:74: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:75: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:76: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:77: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:78: characters 2-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterDropShadow.hx:83: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBlur.hx:32: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBlur.hx:33: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBlur.hx:34: characters 11-23 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBlur.hx:38: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBlur.hx:39: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBlur.hx:40: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:67: characters 16-29 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:68: characters 19-32 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:69: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:70: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:71: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:72: characters 13-27 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:73: characters 13-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:74: characters 18-30 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:83: characters 2-16 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:84: characters 2-16 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:85: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:86: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:87: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:88: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:89: characters 2-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterBevel.hx:95: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:80: characters 14-26 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:83: characters 23-36 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:86: characters 23-35 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:88: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:89: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:90: characters 10-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:91: characters 13-27 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:92: characters 13-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFIXED8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:93: characters 18-30 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:102: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:105: characters 3-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:108: characters 3-16 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:110: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:111: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:112: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:113: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:114: characters 2-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFIXED8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterGradientGlow.hx:120: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:56: characters 12-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:57: characters 12-24 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:58: characters 12-26 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:59: characters 9-23 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:62: characters 15-29 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:64: characters 17-30 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:65: characters 18-30 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:71: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:72: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:73: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:74: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:77: characters 3-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:79: characters 2-16 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeRGBA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterConvolution.hx:83: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterColorMatrix.hx:39: characters 20-34 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/filters/FilterColorMatrix.hx:45: characters 3-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFLOAT
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:50: characters 2-23 : format.swf.SWFData has no field resetBitsPending
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:61: characters 6-19 : format.swf.SWFData has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:62: characters 2-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeDouble
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:63: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:63: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:64: characters 10-30 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUnsignedInt
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:65: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field position
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/utils/HalfPrecisionWriter.hx:123: characters 2-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeShort
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/actions/Action.hx:36: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/actions/Action.hx:38: characters 23-34 : Null<format.swf.SWFData> has no field length
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/actions/Action.hx:39: characters 13-24 : Null<format.swf.SWFData> has no field length
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/actions/Action.hx:40: characters 4-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI16
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/actions/Action.hx:41: characters 4-19 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeBytes
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonCondAction.hx:33: characters 19-31 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonCondAction.hx:33: characters 42-54 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonCondAction.hx:45: characters 19-40 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readACTIONRECORD
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonCondAction.hx:61: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonCondAction.hx:64: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonCondAction.hx:66: characters 3-25 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeACTIONRECORD
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonCondAction.hx:68: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:33: characters 18-30 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:38: characters 16-29 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI16
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:39: characters 15-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI16
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:40: characters 16-31 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readMATRIX
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:42: characters 20-44 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readCXFORMWITHALPHA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:45: characters 30-42 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:47: characters 21-36 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFILTER
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:52: characters 16-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:65: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:66: characters 2-16 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI16
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:67: characters 2-16 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI16
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:68: characters 2-18 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeMATRIX
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:70: characters 3-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeCXFORMWITHALPHA
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:73: characters 4-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:75: characters 5-21 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeFILTER
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFButtonRecord.hx:79: characters 4-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:33: characters 2-23 : format.swf.SWFData has no field resetBitsPending
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:36: characters 6-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:37: characters 23-34 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:38: characters 12-23 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:39: characters 12-23 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:43: characters 6-17 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:44: characters 24-35 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:45: characters 17-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:46: characters 17-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readFB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:48: characters 26-37 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:49: characters 15-26 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFMatrix.hx:50: characters 15-26 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:33: characters 2-23 : format.swf.SWFData has no field resetBitsPending
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:34: characters 17-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:35: characters 18-29 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:36: characters 17-28 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:41: characters 11-22 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:42: characters 11-22 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:43: characters 11-22 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:49: characters 10-21 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:50: characters 10-21 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFColorTransform.hx:51: characters 10-21 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readSB
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFClipActionRecord.hx:28: characters 15-38 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readCLIPEVENTFLAGS
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFClipActionRecord.hx:29: characters 2-15 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI32
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFClipActionRecord.hx:31: characters 13-25 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readUI8
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFClipActionRecord.hx:34: characters 19-40 : format.swf.SWFData has no field readACTIONRECORD
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/swf/2,1,2/format/swf/data/SWFClipActionRecord.hx:41: characters 2-26 : format.swf.SWFData has no field writeCLIPEVENTFLAGS
```

Here is my stack:

```
actuate: 1.8.0 [1.8.6]
assetsmanager: [1.2.0]
box2d: [1.2.3]
cereal: [0.0.4]
hscript: 2.0.4 [2.0.5]
hxcpp: 3.1.48 3.2.102 [3.2.180]
layout: [1.2.1]
lime-samples: [2.6.0]
lime: 2.0.4 2.0.6 2.6.4 2.6.6 2.6.8 [2.6.9]
mlib: [2.0.2]
msignal: [1.2.2]
openfl-samples: 2.2.0 3.3.0 [3.3.1]
openfl: 2.2.1 3.3.5 3.3.6 3.3.8 [3.3.9]
polygonal-core: [1.0.4]
polygonal-ds: [1.4.1]
polygonal-gl: [1.0.4]
polygonal-motor: [0.2.0]
polygonal-printf: [1.0.2-beta]
random: 1.4.0 [1.4.1]
rox-i18n: [1.0.0]
stablexui: 1.1.2 [1.1.5]
svg: [1.0.8]
swf: 1.7.3 2.0.3 2.0.4 2.1.1 [2.1.2]
```

Comment: Try to update to latest swf 2.1.2

Comment: Kindly see my edit above

Comment: I only can propose try on different lib versions, or could you post minimal project, I'll try to build it

Comment: http://lib.haxe.org/p/swf/versions/ 2.1.0 2015-10-02 default to SWFLite on OpenFL native. Maybe try 2.0.4 swf library

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to try to access the library?  Not sure why it's looking in `libraries/` instead of `Assets/`...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the type of the swf library to swflite?

```
<haxelib name="swf" type="swflite" />
```

It needs to be "swflite" for every target except flash. If you need to also compile to flash, you could do:

```
<haxelib name="swf" type="swflite" unless="flash"/>
<haxelib name="swf" type="swf" if="flash" />
```

Comment: If you don't set type, it use swflite or swf, depending on target.

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed that